# How to get the latest record from dynamic div in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

//this is my parent div  and inside this div all child are adding so now I want the latest added child from this parent

@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class="md-requests-list-parent"]")
public WebElement divParent;

public void approveRequest() {

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\\\"md-requests-list-parent\\\"]")));
    List<WebElement> allOptions = select.getOptions();
    int index = allOptions.size();
    select.selectByIndex(index-1);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
List<WebElement> dynamicList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='md-requests-list-parent']"));
int dynamicListSize = dynamicList.size();
WebElement latestOption = dynamicList.get(dynamicListSize - 1);
latestOption.click();
```

When there's a dynamic dropdown, then `Select` won't work. `Select` only works when element locator is `<select>` tag. But in this case, it is `<div>`